# На windows XP поставил Node.js 4.1.0. Какую версию React.js я могу установить? Как мне узнать?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Или я что-то не понимаю. Делал вот так: npm install -g create-react-app@1.5.2. Вроде-что-то там устанавливалось. Потом ввел команду: npm start - выдает ошибки (см.скрин). Посмотрел файл package.json (в папке React), там почему-то написано: "version": "17.0.2". Что-то я тут не понимаю, что происходит. Помогите разобраться?
[image: скрин]

Comment: А посмотрите, есть ли в `package.json` команда `start`?

Comment: Так а create-react-app то вы запустили? Его ж надо не только поставить

Comment: Но в целом зачем такие извращения?

Answer (score 0):

Заставить `create-react-app` создать конфигурацию под `node 4.1` в настоящее время невозможно, но это несложно сделать самостоятельно:

1. Создаем папку приложения, например *legacy_app*
2. В ней создаем файл *package.json* с таким содержимым:

```
{
  "name": "legacy_app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "~15.3.0",
    "react-dom": "~15.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-scripts": "~0.6.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "~15.3.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom"
  }
}
```

3. Открываем в нашей папке командную консоль и выполняем `npm install`
4. После успешной установки пакетов создаем каркас приложения (копируем из папки *node_modules\react-scripts\template*) командой:

```
xcopy /S node_modules\react-scripts\template .
```

5. Запускаем приложение командой `npm start`